# Execute a shell command in C but not through web page

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have a program in C/java/html 5

The service file of the program runs as root user and it is on an Archlinux distribution.

I want to have the result IP address that SMB will find and show it in an html page i have.

The part of the code i am interested is this:

```
sds ns_server_list(sds buffer, sds method, int request_id)
{
    FILE *fp = popen("/usr/bin/nmblookup -S \'*\' | grep \"<00>\" | awk \'{print $1}\'", "r");
    // returns three lines per server found - 1st line ip address 2nd line name 3rd line workgroup
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed to get server list");
        buffer = jsonrpc_respond_message(buffer, method, request_id, "Failed to get server list", true);
    }
```

If i run the program through shell (./test) and after compile, it returns the results in HTML just fine.

If i run it through the web interface of program and through a service file, it returns these SMB errors in journalctl -xe:

> WARNING: no network interfaces found 
> name_query failed to find name *  
> ERROR    Executing syscmd "/usr/bin/nmblookup -S '*'" failed

SMB.conf

```
[global]
server string = SMB Server
security = user
guest account = root
map to guest = bad user
log level = 0
load printers = No
syslog = 0
directory mask = 0775
create mask = 0775
browseable = yes
#veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/
interfaces = eth0 192.168.2.0/24
```

Summarized...

If i run the program through service file and without IP address in SMB.conf i have the errors in journalctl. If i put the IP everything is ok but i do not want to work it like this way (dynamic ip and eth0 do not work, same errors).

If i run the program through shell with the executable compiled file (./test) everything play fine without ip address in smb.conf

Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing more about your setup.  For example, what's in test.sh, what's in your smb.conf, what user are you running test.sh as.

That being said, googling your error "WARNING: no network interfaces found" turns up this result:

https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-165159-start-0.html

Which suggests defining an interface in smb.conf. If you don't have an interface defined in smb.conf, try defining one?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right. I run the .sh with root privileges. If i put my ip address i do not have that error and everything is fine but i cannot use this approach because the machine has a dynamic ip.

Comment: Gotcha. So I believe there is a way to define the smb.conf to pull the dynamic IP.  Here are the docs about smb.conf. https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/4.7/man-html/smb.conf.5.html.  From the docs it looks like something like interfaces = eth0 might work (and it will pull the IP dynamically).

Comment: it is not an .sh file. It is the compiled file of the program. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes Nicholas. But i do not know why it runs fine  from shell (Putty) without the IP and i have to enter the IP in smb.conf when i run it through the HTML page.

Comment: i tried with eth0(which is the actual name in ifconfig of the net interface) and eth* but same error appears.

Comment: I don't have an answer other than to try various things and see what works. see if the documentation for smb.conf mentions a way to set the IP dynamically, or via placeholders. Look at the nmblookup docs to see if there are options that might avoid the need to lookup your IP address. The -B flag looks like it *might* allow you to avoid defining the interface in smb.conf by directly giving the broadcast address.  So something like nmblookup -B 192.168.2.255 might work.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas for your time! I will try it...

Comment: Why do you have backslashes before the single quotes?

Comment: (Not that that has anything to do with the problem; there's just no point to them there, they're only appropriate before _double_ quotes).

Comment: ...as for the actual problem, we require questions to be about _specific_, _narrow_ issues. There's a lot more narrowing-down that would need to happen for this to be on-topic.

Comment: For example: Is it **really** only a problem when the command is run **from a shell**? If you directly `execve()`-invoke `char[][]{"nmblookup", "-S", "*"}` (from the same service with its appropriate process environment/cgroups/etc), does it fail the same way? (If it does, the claim that it was a shell-specific problem was false).

Comment: One place I generally recommend starting, wrt. trying to narrow down a problem, is to use a cross-process syscall-level tracing tool to dig in. My personal favorite is [`sysdig`](http://sysdig.org/), but there are lots to choose from; you might find http://www.brendangregg.com/ebpf.html a good place to start for the platform that most of sysdig's worthy competitors are built on.